# how to get s3 bucket size via aws-sdk (javascript or node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I tried to find/get s3 bucket information using javascript/nodejs aws-sdk, but I didnt find such apis. How to get s3 bucket size / information  via aws-sdk (javascript or node) api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to get the bucket size other than enumerating all the objects.

One alternative approach would be to investigate the billing, but I think that will only yield inaccurate data as the billing handles a specific size over a specific time.

Comment: hi @Dave, your answer is 2 yrs old, is there any api which now gives the size of bucket directly ?

Answer (score 4):

Once a day the size of the bucket is reported to CloudWatch. The Metric is called BucketSizeBytes and you can supply the BucketName as a dimension and the StorageType (AllStorageTypes, StandardStorage, StandardIAStorage, ReducedRedundancyStorage).

You can use the JavaScript SDK to acceess the data in CloudWatch via the getMetricStatistics of the CloudWatch client. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricStatistics-property

Comment: hi @hellomichibye, your answer is 4 yrs old, is there any api which now gives the size of bucket directly ?